# How to print two phone numbers with spaces in the same row using jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to print two numbers in the same row with spaces or commas as 
442233378,556664446 in this way I need to print using jasper reports.I am using the variable as $F(alias_name) to print these numbers.But it is printing out of the page as shown in the image it has to print the number above the line where the first number is printed.Please help me.

Comment: You should post your *jrxml* file and improve the problem's decription

Comment: OK can I add () for textfieldespression.Please help me

Comment: ($F{paid_amount} == null)?(new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00")).format(0):(new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00")).format($F{paid_amount}) I need to print this expression between the ().It is not working for me.Please help me.

Comment: What is a right result for you?

Comment: the expression is printing correctly but i want to print (expresion) in this way

Comment: Like this: "(" + $F{strValue} + ")" ?

Comment: Can you please add for my expression.it is showing syntax error

Comment: $V{total} == null ? "(0.00)" : "(" + new DecimalFormat ("#,##0.00").format($V{total}) + ")"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101374/discussion-between-alex-k-and-mouni).

Comment: BigDecimal total = null;
String str = total == null ? "(0.00)" : "(" + new DecimalFormat ("#,##0.00").format(total) + ")"; - this is correct snippet from *Java* code

Comment: You should set *Java* as language for your report

Comment: why it is duplicate it formatting a string to currency it is not the right solution for me.You need to give a possible answer already i have seen that question and i asked in this.Please help me.It is very important for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101397/discussion-between-mouni-and-alex-k).

Comment: Could you specify what type of database you are using? An easier solution could be possible through editing of the query itself.

Comment: can we get the list of the id's and can convert into array and print is it possible??

Comment: I have used this quey <queryString>
  <![CDATA[select alias_name from service_alias where service_id in(select id from service where order_id in (select id from purchase_order where id in (select order_id from order_process where invoice_id = $P{invoiceId}) and period_id!=1) and status_id=47 and deleted=0) and deleted=0 order by id limit 2;]]>
 </queryString> but it is printing the same as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get get a solution for this by just changing your query.
I have added a `GROUP_CONCAT` function onto your `alias_name` field, you can read more on what this does [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT alias_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS alias_name
FROM
  service_alias
WHERE
  service_id IN
    (
      SELECT
        id
      FROM
        service
      WHERE
        order_id IN
          (
            SELECT
              id
            FROM
              purchase_order
            WHERE
              id IN
                (
                  SELECT
                    order_id
                  FROM
                    order_process
                  WHERE
                    invoice_id = $P{invoiceId}
                )
            AND
              period_id != 1
          )
    )
```

Here is the query added into the entityDetails.jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Entity details" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="875" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="invoiceId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<queryString>
 <![CDATA[
   SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT alias_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS alias_name
   FROM
     service_alias
   WHERE
     service_id IN
       (
         SELECT
           id
         FROM
           service
         WHERE
           order_id IN
             (
               SELECT
                 id
               FROM
                 purchase_order
               WHERE
                 id IN
                   (
                     SELECT
                       order_id
                     FROM
                       order_process
                     WHERE
                       invoice_id = $P{invoiceId}
                   )
               AND
                 period_id!=1
             )
       )
 ]]>
</queryString>
 <field name="alias_name" class="java.lang.String"/> 
<title>
 <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<detail>
 <band height="62">
     <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
         <reportElement x="50" y="5" width="197" height="15" />
         <textElement>
             <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
         </textElement>
         <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{alias_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
     </textField>
     <image>
         <reportElement x="18" y="4" width="18" height="13" />
         <imageExpression><![CDATA["/opt/apps/openbrm-2.0/openbrm/resources/logos/phone-symbol.png"]]></imageExpression>
     </image>
 </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: can I add this query in my code <querystring> tag

Comment: it is getting error as alias_name unknown column after adding your query

Comment: @Mouni Which column is not working?

Comment: unknown column ailas_name is showing as error after adding the answer

Comment: I have now changed the answer to a corrected query (hopefully) and to include the jrxml code as well.

Comment: Ok but at the end it is showing "," how to remove it

Comment: @Cameron Please help me how to remove comma at the end

Comment: This may be because your text field isn't large enough to show all of the contents of the field. Do you know how many alias_names are being returned on your query?